# Почему не работает импорт модуля?

Tags: nextjs, next.js

Переношу приложение на next.js и почему то пишет, что модуль не найден, хотя оно прямо указывает на него путь в ошибке.

Импортирую так:

```
import InputMask from "react-input-mask";
```

Ошибка такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо, для react-input-mask нужен react. он установлен?

Comment: @nörbörnën Конечно, вот package.json: {
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.5.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-modal": "^3.11.2"
  }
}

Comment: он есть в package.json, установлен (npm i)? если всё установлено то попробуй просто добавить `import * as React from "react"` перед `import InputMask from "react-input-mask"`

Comment: @nörbörnën все равно не помогло.

Comment: @nörbörnën все еще раз переустановил через npx create-next-app, а не по гайду из учебника отсюда: https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup и все заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переустановил через npx create-next-app, а не:

`npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/tree/master/learn-starter"`   [отсюда](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app/setup) и все заработало.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/531493)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor спасибо, поправил.

Comment: MrYogurt, ok ;)